# scipy cobyla doesn't converge

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am having a problem using fmin_cobyla. I am using it to for parameter fitting. For some reason, it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop even the problem is correctly defined. I turned on iprint it is looping the following message. Does anyone know what this means ?

```
RESMAX,MCON, M, ICON = 0.0000000 2 1 0
ICOUNT, OPTNEW, OPTOLD, 0 NAN 0.00000
*TOT,NACT, ICON = NAN 1 2
2. VMULTD = NAN 0.000000
3. VMULTD = NAN 0.00000
3. VMULTC = 0.0000
```

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: That possibly means your objective function has returned a NaN value, confusing the optimizer. Alternatively, the optimizer has itself ended in some singular situation. Difficult to say much more based on this information. If you have a simple test case producing this behavior, that might help.

Comment: i checked the return value of my objective function and it is non nan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. The reason for this is because rhobeg I used was a function. When rhobeg was negative, it caused it to enter an infinite loop!!!